# `nix-shell -p [package] --command [command]`

Tags: nix

I'm trying to run a command in script using `nix-shell -p [package] --command [comand]` and getting an error `Permission denied` on files, that the command needs to operate on. The command needs only read access and if I try to do `nix-shell -p [package]` and then run the `[command]` there by hand, then everything is okay, but if I try to do it through the `--command [command]` it gives me an error. Why is that?

Edit:

The command looks like this: `nix-shell -p ormolu --command "ormolu --mode check $(find . -name '*.hs')"`

Comment: Please, post the whole script which is not working. It's impossible to guess what's wrong with what you have provided

Comment: @vitalii done, this command isn't working when I'm trying to run it in NixOS.

Comment: @vitalii I mean, when I'm trying to just run this one command in terminal in my Nix installation it doesn't work.

Comment: [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) applies; `some-command $(find ...)` is a bad idea in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `nix-shell` (or `ormolu`). Try this instead:

```bash
nix-shell -p ormolu --command "find . -name '*.hs' -exec ormolu --mode check {} + "
```

The reason you've got `permission denied` is that you actually passing the first output of the `find` command to ormolu, and trying to execute the rest of the `.hs` files.